# How to feed code into iframe without a URL or FILE?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to create a visual editor where the user creates a 3D scene, and my application writes the code for the project itself. I want to create a testing feature where the code that was generated is run. I've looked into using `iframes`, but as far as I know, you need a specific `URL` for `iframe`.

Here are some ideas/solutions I've come up with:

- ***Is there a way to manually feed code to an `iframe`, without a file or URL?***
- ***Is there any other easier way to accomplish this task?***
- ***Can this be done without server side code?***

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible however a much simpler way would be to just create another html file somewhere on your server/host and just disallow external access to it so it's only accessible from the `iframe`.

You have to use an script to give code to an `iframe` without a source file like this:

```html
<iframe id="my-iframe"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById("my-iframe").contentDocument.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
</script>
```

Change the JavaScript to this to overwrite all of the content of the `iframe`:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("my-iframe");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframeDocument.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Goodbye World</h1>";
```

This overwrites all the content of the `iframe` with your own.

This will work but it will be a big pain to format the html from the `iframe`. Also as far as I know this is the simplest way that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Exactly what I was wondering!

Comment: No problem, however can you please mark my answer as the solution? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: yes i need to wait 30 more seconds

Comment: Yep, I will edit my answer

Comment: No problem! Also why did you remove your question from the comments?

Comment: Sorry, I was having some problems