# How can I manually append three.js code into an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, three.js

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862017/how-to-feed-code-into-iframe-without-a-url-or-file) question on SO, asking how to feed code into an `iframe` WITHOUT a file or url. This worked in simple cases, like `<h1>Hello World</h1>`, but in the long run, I want to implement `three.js` into these `iframes`. Here is how I tried adding to the `iframe`:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("my-iframe");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframeDocument.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
```

This works fine, but now I try to create a *very* simple `three.js` scene, just to kick things off. Here is how I tried it:

```js
generatedCode = `\
    <!DOCTYPE html>\
    <html>\
        <head>\
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r134/three.min.js" ></script>\
        </head>\
        <body style="margin: 0;">\
            <script>\
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();\
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);\
        \
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(\
            new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1),\
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000})\
        );\
        \
        scene.add(mesh);\
        \
        camera.position.z = -5;\
        camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);\
        \
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();\
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);\
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);\
    \
    function animate(){\
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);\
        renderer.render(scene, camera);\
    }\
    \
    animate();\
        </script>\
        </body>\
    </html>\
    `
```

Just a variable, sorry if this isn't the best way to do things. After defining this variable, I apply it the same way:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("my-iframe");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframeDocument.body.innerHTML = generatedCode; //Now using the variable instead of a heading
```

Why doesn't this work? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what doesn't work? Empty `iframe`? Any errors in console?

Comment: Also the variable names don't match. `generatedCode` != `generatedContent`

Comment: Also remember that an `iframe` is an isolated environment which means that the code from inside the `iframe` can't affect the outside and vice versa.

Comment: @nnaem There are no errors in the console, and the inconsistency of the variable names was just a typo on SO. Nothing shows up on my screen, so I'm not sure what's going on here... Thanks for your repeated help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `generatedCode` will produce error `Unterminated template literal` you need to escape/replace `</script>` in variable with `<\/script>`

because the variable start with `<!DOCTYPE html><html>` it better to write the iframe using `iframeDocument.write()`, becasuse the `iframeDocument.body.innerHTML` is to write in `<body>`

run on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrw3ke75/)

```js
let generatedCode = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r134/three.min.js"><\/script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xff0000
        }));
        scene.add(mesh);
        camera.position.z = -5;
        camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        animate();
    <\/script>
</body>

</html>`;

var iframe = document.getElementById("my-iframe");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframeDocument.write(generatedCode);
iframeDocument.close();
```

```html
<iframe id="my-iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The thing is, when I use `document.write()`, it gives me a violation and "strongly recommends" to not use it? Also, do I only need to do `<\/..` on `script` tags?

Comment: about `violation` message you can ignore it, because its not even `warning log` or use `iframeDocument.body.innerHTML` and rebuild variable `generatedCode` to include only `<script src="...">` and `<script>` .  the escape `<\/.. ` is only for  `script`

Comment: Okay... it seems like this `iframe` only works sometimes? I would say 1/5 times it shows as expected, otherwise it just shows white?

Comment: make sure code in block `<script>...</script>` executed after  `<script src="...">` loaded

Answer (score 1):

Provided the parent window is considered to be of the same origin, code in an iframe element can access its parent window using `window.parent`, or the top most window in a group of nested iframes as `window.top`. And global variables declared using `var` can be accessed as window properties.

The example below uses `document.write` because, without further testing, it compiled the script written to the iframe document - there may be other ways of doing it. The script written calls a test function in the parent iframe, which logs text on the console.

**This code doesn't work on Stack Overflow** (which triggers a not-same origin error) but testd successfully when when loaded in a browser :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Iframe Access</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Parent window</h1>

<iframe id="my-iframe"></iframe>


<script>"use strict";
  var test = ()=>console.log("test() call in parent window");
  var iframe = document.getElementById("my-iframe");
  var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  iframeDocument.open();
  iframeDocument.write( `
    <h1>iframe Body</h1>
    Check the console for output...
    <script>
      console.log(window.parent);
      window.parent.test();
   <\/script>`
  );
  iframeDocument.close();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Returning to the question, the first thing to try from the parent frame might be

```
iframe.contentWindow.generateContent = generateContent
```

which would make `generateContent` a property of the window within the iframe. It says nothing about whether `generateContent` will run under such circumstances!

Comment: Okay, so that seemed to work - kind of. The iframe only loads sometimes, it may work as expected, but otherwise the webpage just shows white - no errors. Do you know what's happening here?

Comment: Okay, I've reread the question after mistakenly assuming `generatedCode` was a function :(  Try document writing the generated code to the iframe as shown in the stack snippet where it writes a template literal to the iframe's document element. Don't forget to open and close the document before and afterwards. Setting `innerHTML` does not compile script elements if I recall correctly. I'll update the answer (if it works) later.